New website design - lost 30-40% of traffic - traffic has not recovered
My website www.westroofingsystems.com got a new design in June 2023. The goal was to increase speed on mobile. My traffic has gone down considerably since then (30-40%) and has not recovered. I would understand a redesign hurting traffic for a month or two, but to never recover, something must be wrong SEO-wise. Does anyone have any idea why this happened? Thank you so much!

Has the content changed?  That's a HUGE part of SEO.  A lot of people want simplified designs with little to no text and suddenly their search ratings drop.  Also, it may be that your new site is less appealing to bots, so they stop visiting.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I have checked your site and come for the possible reasons.

Please check if the domain you bought belongs to you from the start as google downgrade the OLD Domain concept because of spamming in their recent updates and this is one of the reasons that Traffic has been lost.
AI content is also downgraded in google recent updates.
Check your Google Analytic, Search Console to find if there is any issue in your site.

Last: Hire an SEO Person for Short Term to review and apply possible fix to your website.
